# How to install gumbo.h for C++?

Tags: c++, linux, virtualbox, gumbo

I am running LXLE on an Oracle VirtualBox computer. I have successfully installed gumbo for python, but I cannot find how to install the gumbo library for C++, so that if I have a C++ file that includes `gumbo.h` in the headers, it will actually run.

I am trying to compile a file called `countWordsInSite_iterative.cpp` using the following command:

```
g++ countWordsInSite_iterative.cpp -o countWordsInSite -lcurl -lgumbo -g
```

I get the following error:

```
countWordsInSite_iterative.cpp:32:10: fatal error: gumbo/gumbo.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gumbo/gumbo.h>  // For HTML parser
```

How can I install the necessary files to include `gumbo.h`?

Comment: Please clarify which installation and usage instructions you've been following. [The Readme](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) seems comprehensive. Is there something there that didn't work for you? If so, clarify what exactly that is. Otherwise all we can do is simply repeat the entire Readme here, which is not useful to anybody.

Comment: Your already installed "python gumbo" is python bindings for Gumbo HTML parser https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser ... which includes `gumbo.h`

Comment: I am Brand New to Linux, and do not have much experience. I found 2 gumbo files on my computer, libgumbo1 and libgumbo-dev. They both reside in usr/share/doc. I am not sure where they are supposed to go, or how I am supposed to unpack them. I apologize for being a complete noob.